# How do I find the ideals in the ring $\mathbb F_3[x]/(x^2+2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

Clearly $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb F_3[x]/(x^2+2)$ will be ideals. How would I find the others?

Comment: Can you factor $x^2+2$?

Comment: The same way you do in any polynomial ring over a field: you find the divisors of $x^2+2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $x^2 +2 \equiv (x+1)(x+2)$ mod $3$

Comment: Good! You can then use the factors to find ideals much like you would use factors of $6$ to find ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_6$. BTW, have you heard of the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Or the variant of correspondence theorem involving rings and ideals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $x^2+2=x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

Now recall that $F_3[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.